# Laravel - Model BelongsTo multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a system and I have a question, in the system I have 3 main models (User, State, City), to manage the users I use a package for Laravel called [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust), with this package I can define system roles, one of these roles is the `manager`, the `manager` can have `Cities` and `States`, however, a `States` can have several `Cities`, so in my model `Cities` `BelongsTo` to a `User` and a `States`.

Is that correct? A model can `BelongsTo` more then one model? I found no satisfactory answer on Google.

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use SearchableTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'role',
        'active',
        'status',
        'name',
        'slug',
        'email',
        'password',
        'cpf',
        'rg',
        'mothers_name',
        'marital_status',
        'curriculum',
        'psychiatric_report',
        'contract',
        'phone',
        'adress',
        'city',
        'state',
        'country',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $searchable = [
        'columns' => [
            'users.name' => 10,
            'users.slug' => 8,
            'users.email' => 8,
        ]
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function states()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\State');
    }

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
```

State.php

```
class State extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'initials',
        'manager_id'
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function manager(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
```

City.php

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'state_id',
        'manager_id',
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function manager(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function state(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep it simple. Let cities belong to States. So By city you can get its belonging state. And from state you can get its cities.

Comment: @rahulsm and about the manager?

Comment: Who is belongs to User. So indirectly, user will be manager. So relation for User/Manager with state and city, you can keep as is